# Comparing two numbers in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I want to compare two numbers, but the comparison is not working

```
read x
read y

if["$x" -lt "$y"]
then
     echo "X is less than Y"
elif["$x" -gt "$y"]
then
     echo "X is greater than Y"
elif["$x" -eq "$y"]
then
    echo "X is equal to Y"
fi
```

And when the inputs are given as `x = 5` and `y = 2`

I get following Runtime Error:

```
solution.sh: line 4: if[5 -lt 2]: command not found
solution.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
solution.sh: line 5: `then
```

Comment: You need one space character around all the `[` and `]` in conditional statements in Bash

Comment: resolved the problem:read x
read y

if(($x < $y));
then 
    echo "X is less than Y"
 fi   
if(($x > $y));
then
    echo "X is greater than Y"
    fi
 
if(($x == $y));
then
    echo "X is equal to Y"
 fi